# Zoom in / adjust styling on RDA plot

Tags: r, plot

I am new to R, and I am making an RDA chart with plot of some data obtained with `vegan` and `adespatial` packages, the chart that generates me is the following

**Graph generated**

[image]

The graph is correct, but aesthetically it is not good, because the interpretation of it is difficult since you can not even appreciate the names, what I want is to be able to somehow modify the scale in order that the data look more dispersed and thus appreciate the data.

I would like my graphic to look something like this, where you can see at least the initials of the names

**Example chart**

[image]

My code with which I generate the graph is the following

```
windows(width = 12, height = 10)

par(mar=c(3,3,1,1), mgp=c(2,1,0), cex=0.8, maii=c(0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1))

plot(str.rda, xlab="RDA1 (32.16 %)", ylab="RDA2 (14.46 %)", display=c("cn", "lc", "sp"), type="n", xlim=c(-0.8,0.8),correlation=TRUE)

sites.sc <- scores(str.rda, choices=1:2, scaling=2, display="lc")
points(sites.sc, pch=1, cex=0.5)
text(sites.sc,row.names(sites.sc), cex = 0.6, pos = 4, col = "chocolate1")

va.sc <- scores(str.rda, choices=1:2, scaling=2, display="sp")
sp.names<- c("Americabaetis", "Baetodes", "Camelobaetidius", "Cloeodes", "Nanomis","Varipes","Zelusia","Caenis", "Trichorythodes",  "Lumahyphes","Farrodes","Thraulodes", "Anacroneuria", "Protoptila","Helicopsyche", "Leptonema", "Smicridea", "Alisotrichia", "Celaenotrichia", "Cerasmatrichia", "Hydroptila", "Metrichia", "Neotrichia", "Orthotrichia", "Oxyethira", "Rhyacopsyche", "Chimarra")
text(va.sc[c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21,22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27 ),], sp.names[c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21,22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27 )], cex=0.8, font=3, pos=3,offset=0.1)

env.sc <- scores(str.rda, choices=1:2, scaling=2, display="bp")
arrows(0,0, env.sc[1:3,1], env.sc[1:3,2], lty=1, lwd=1, col="Blue", length=0.1)

env.names <- c("DQO", "DBO", "Turbidez")
text(env.sc[c(1,2,3),], env.names[c(1,2,3)], cex=0.9, font=2, pos=2,offset = 0.1)
```

I was reading and I found several alternatives such as modifying `xlim` (lowest value, highest value) and `ylim` (lowest value, highest value), however the graph keeps coming out in the same way, so I don't know what I can do to improve it aesthetically, I appreciate your attention and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you should be aware of is that using `plot(str.rda)` will actually call 
`vegan:::plot.cca()` that does not behave as `plot.default()`. In order to overcome avoid this, you can simply use an empty plot with two points:

```
plot(c(-1, 1), c(-.8, .8), xlab="RDA1 (32.16 %)", ylab="RDA2 (14.46 %)", type="n")
abline(h = 0, v = 0, lty = 2, lwd =.5) # add x=0 and y=0 guide lines
# then you can add the rest of your code
```

Note that with this, `xlim` and `ylim` will behave the way you expected. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello friend, I already did what you mentioned and it actually works, which looks a little bigger, but not as much as you would like, do you have any other ideas with which you can increase that size? Thank you very much for your collaboration, I leave you the link of the image obtained https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z2q3q5wHFbi5_KVej0XHujo4fO5Xy1GB/view?usp=sharing

Comment: :) Can you be more specific about the size you are referring too. The size of the plots? The size of a specific element?

Comment: Of course, my friend, I mean the size of the black cluster, I want it to be bigger to be able to appreciate it a little better, the truth is that my knowledge in r is basic, and in advance I apologize for the terms, but in general I wish I could make the graph readable (that the names of the species can be seen), because a black cluster is formed that does not know what it says

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You can use narrow down the ranges of x and y axes but I doubt it will be any better. You may consider using numbers of letters and a caption to make it more readable.

Comment: Thanks friend, I'm going to try it